# Change material properties of elements in named selection in Ansys workbench using APDL commands

Tags: ansys-workbench, ansys-apdl

How to change the material properties, i.e. Young's modulus and Poisson's ratio, of a set of elements which is defined by a named selection in Ansys workbench using a command snippet of APDL code?

The named selection is denoted `steelElements`.
An appropriate material, named `Structural Steel` is defined in an "engineering data" system.

Answer (score 1):

## Strategy:

- Identify maximum number of material properties
- Create material
- Assign material to selected elements

## Code:

```
    !   Commands inserted into this file will be executed just prior to the ANSYS SOLVE command.
    !   These commands may supersede command settings set by Workbench.

    !   Active UNIT system in Workbench when this object was created:  Metric (mm, t, N, s, mV, mA)
    !   NOTE:  Any data that requires units (such as mass) is assumed to be in the consistent solver unit system.
    !                See Solving Units in the help system for more information.
    FINISH
    /PREP7
    *DEL,mySelectioName,,nopr 
    *DIM, mySelectioName, string, 248, 1
    !################### Start User Input
    myEModul = 210000
    myPoissionration = 0.3
    mySelectioName(1, 1) = 'steelElements'
    !################### End User Input
    ALLSEL
    !Get maximal material number assigned and increment
    *GET,maxMaterialNumber,ELEM,0,MATM
    maxMaterialNumber = maxMaterialNumber + 1
    !Create new material properties
    MP, EX, maxMaterialNumber, myEModul
    MP, NUXY, maxMaterialNumber, myPoissionration
    !Select elements and change material property number of those materials
    CMSEL,s,mySelectioName(1, 1)
    MPCHG, maxMaterialNumber, all
    !Select all entities and leave code snippet
    ALLSEL
    FINISH
    /SOLU

    ! Doublecheck in Classic:
    !   /pnum,mat,1 !0=off, 1=on
    !   /number,1   !0=on, 1=off
```

Comment: To get the maximum material number defined, you should use: `*GET, maxMaterialNumber, MAT, 0, NUM, MAX `